# JQUERY mobile space below footer

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I wrote the following code:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="myPage.php"><img src="MyImg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="myPage.php"><img src="MyImg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"> 
                    <a href="myPage.php"><img src="MyImg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="myPage.php"><img src="MyImg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm using jquery-mobile, everything fits well the screen, but there is a white space under the footer...how can I remove this space in order to have "footer" div at the very bottom of the page?

Comment: Can you Post you `CSS` Code.?

Comment: Add `data-position="fixed"` to footer div.

Comment: Thanks, Omar hint solved the issue!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-positon="fixed">
....
</div>
```

You can read up on fixed possition at [jquerymobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)